# Arc Length and Area of a Sector

Tags: geometry, contest-math

A cake has a circumference of $30 \mathrm{cm}$ and a uniform height of $7\mathrm{cm}$. A slice is to be cut from the cake with two straight cuts meeting at the centre. If the slice is to contain $50\mathrm{cm^3}$ of cake, find the angle between the two cuts, giving the answer in radians to $2$ significant figures and in degrees correct to the nearest degree.

Comment: Please show some work. Here are bite-sized pieces:

Comment: 1. What is the radius of the cake?

Comment: 2. What is the volume of the cake?

Comment: 3. Now that you know the formula for sector area, can you find theta?

Comment: Do we make the area of the sector equal to the volume?

Comment: The area of the sector, times its height, give its volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that arc length = $\theta r$ and that the area of a sector = $\frac{\theta}{2} r^2$ where the angle theta is in **radians**

EDIT:

I left out a bit of information that might help you answer this question.

C = $2\pi r$
30 = $2\pi r$

You are also given the volume of the cut to be $50cm^3$. You can use this and the uniform height given to calculate the area of the cut (which just so happens to be the area of the sector). Once you've got this, you can substitute in the value for the radius, and find the angle $\theta$.
I will assume you know how to use significant figures and how to convert from radians to degrees.

Comment: How do we apply those in this question?

Comment: Note that volume = area * height, and you have 2 of those quantities already.